# Pythonのargparseで特定のオプションが指定されている時はrequiredを抑制したい

Tags: python

以下の例では`-m`をrequired指定していますが、`--version`が指定されたときは、`-m`が未指定でも、バージョン情報を出力して終了する、ということをやりたいです。何か方法はないでしょうか？

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import pkg_resources
import sys
import argparse

argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description='This tool will help local development of mbed',
    formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter
)
argparser.add_argument(
    '-m', '--target',
    required=True,
    help='Compile target MCU. @see https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-cli')

argparser.add_argument(
    '--version',
    required=False,
    default=False,
    action='store_true',
    help='Print version info')

args = argparser.parse_args()

if args.version:
    print('xmbedinit {}'.format(
        pkg_resources.require('xmbedinit')[0].version))
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`--version` に関しては、ご所望の動作をするような action として `'version'` が用意されています。

```
argparser.add_argument('--version', action='version', version='%(prog)s 2.0')
```

参考: [argparse のドキュメントにおける action の節](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action)

Comment: 専用のオプションがあるんですね。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

すでに承認回答がついてしまっていますが、[相互排他グループ](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion)を使うと`--version`以外の場合も対応できそうですね。`-m`と`--version`のORをとったオプションを作ってそれ自体を`required`にしてしまうという方法です。

```
group = argparser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)

group.add_argument(
    '-m', '--target',
    help='Compile target MCU. @see https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-cli')

group.add_argument(
    '--version',
    default=False,
    action='store_true',
    help='Print version info')
```

```
% python3 test.py 
usage: test.py [-h] (-m TARGET | --version)
test.py: error: one of the arguments -m/--target --version is required
```

ただ、`--version`のような特殊なオプションの場合は、このようなメッセージは不親切な気もしますね。またmasmさんの指摘にもあるとおり、あくまでも相互排他であるため両方のオプションを同時に指定できません。

Comment: mutually exclusive なので、両方を指定した場合に、両方同時には指定できない旨のメッセージが出そうに思います。